# Event Action returns returns null after another class fires the Event

Tags: c#

So here's the story, I have three forms and two classes, I am currently have information being sent to form1 just fine. Now when I try to send data from the same class (or the other) to form2, `public event Action<string> updateMainLabelconn;` returns null.

Here is the tactic that I am trying and is the one that works when talking to form1:

```
public class Connection
   {
   public Form2 form2;
   public event Action<string> updateMainLabelconn;
   //There is other methods that call to this method and it works correctly.
   public void LE1_Update(object sender, InstrumentLookupSubscriptionEventArgs e)
   {
    updateMainLabelconn("INSTRUMENT LOADED : " + e.Instrument.InstrumentDetails.Name.ToString());
   }
}

public partial class Form2 : Form
   {
    public Connection conn;
    public Form2()
   {
    InitializeComponent();

    conn = new Connection();
    conn.updateMainLabelconn += MainStatusUpdateconn;
    }
   public void MainStatusUpdateconn(string e)
   {
   mainStatus.Text = e;
   }
```

So that's the crucial parts of the code, I think, if I missed something then feel free to rip me a new one! haha

Comment: Any errors being thrown?

Comment: Yes, the updateMainLableconn returns a 'System.NullReferenceException'  because the action is null.

Comment: Hmm I don't have time to run this on my side, but it seems to me that your LE1_Update is not creating an action, maybe something like action(updateMainLabelconn("INSTRUMENT LOADED : " + e.Instrument.InstrumentDetails.Name.ToString())); ?  Psudo code, but I think that's the problem area...

Comment: So, how is `LE1_Update` being called? is it through a `Form2` instance?